# How do I find the outward unit vectors which are normal to the surface of the sphere at the intersection points of the ray and the sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, 3d

Consider the surface of the sphere given by the equation $$(x − 3)^2 + (y − 4)^2 + z^2 = 25.$$ You shoot a ray from the point $(8, 4, 0)$ along the vector $v = \langle1, 0, 1\rangle$.

What are the outward unit vectors normal to the surface of the sphere at the intersection points of the ray and the sphere?

I found the two intersection points, which are $(8, 4, 0)$ and $(3, 4, −5)$. The answer to this question are the vectors $\langle 1, 0, 0\rangle$ and $\langle 0, 0, -1\rangle$, but I don't know how they got here from the two intersection points.

Comment: Hint: For a sphere centered at the origin, the position vector of a point on its surface is also an outward normal at that point. So, ...

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this step by step.  I'll use notation $(x, y, z) = \left[\begin{matrix} x & y & z \end{matrix} \right]^T = \left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix}\right]$ for vectors for brevity.

You have
$$(x - 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2 + (z - 0)^2 = 25$$
which describes a sphere of radius $r = 5$ centered at $\vec{c} = (x_c, y_c, z_c) = (3, 4, 0)$:
$$(x - x_c)^2 + (y - y_c)^2 + (z - z_c)^2 = r^2$$
If we use $\vec{p} = (x, y, z)$, we can write this in vector form as
$$(\vec{p} - \vec{c}) \cdot (\vec{p} - \vec{c}) = r^2$$

You also have a ray that starts at $\vec{p}_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0) = (8, 4, 0)$, in direction $\vec{v} = (x_v, y_v, z_v) = (1, 0, 1)$.  As a vector-valued function, we can parametrize the ray using $0 \le t \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\vec{p}(t) = \vec{p}_0 + t \vec{v}$$
or in Cartesian coordinate form,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x(t) &= x_0 + t x_v \\
y(t) &= y_0 + t y_v \\
z(t) &= z_0 + t z_v \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$

The intersection occurs at when $\vec{p}$ fulfills the first equation, using $\vec{p}(t)$ for $\vec{p}$:
$$\Bigr((\vec{p}_0 + t \vec{v}) - \vec{c}\Bigr) \cdot \Bigr((\vec{p}_0 + t \vec{v}) - \vec{c}\Bigr) = r^2$$
or, equivalently in Cartesian coordinate form,
$$(x_0 + t x_v - x_c)^2 + (y_0 + t y_v - y_c)^2 + (z_0 + t z_v - z_c)^2 = r^2$$
Solving for $0 \le t \in \mathbb{R}$ tells you if and where ($\vec{p}(t)$) the ray and the sphere intersect.  You discard solutions where $t \lt 0$, because they occur "before" the starting point of the ray.  If $\lVert\vec{v}\rVert = 1$, then $t$ is also the distance from the starting point to the intersection, but generally the distance is $t\lVert\vec{v}\rVert$, i.e. in units of direction vector Euclidean length.

In this case, the two solutions are $t = 0$ corresponding to $\vec{p}(0) = (8, 4, 0)$ and $t = -5$ corresponding to $\vec{p}(-5) = (3, 4, -5)$.  This means that the starting position of the ray intersects the sphere, as does $t = -5$. However, $t = -5$ is in the opposite direction of the ray, so whether you wish to consider that case or not depends on the context.  Usually $t = -5$ would not be considered.

As amd commented, every point on an unit sphere is also the normal vector on that sphere.  More generally, given point $\vec{p}$ at distance $r$ from center of sphere $\vec{c}$, the unit normal vector is
$$\hat{n} = \frac{\vec{p} - \vec{c}}{r} = \frac{\vec{p} - \vec{c}}{\left\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{c} \right\rVert}$$

In OP's case, the points are $(8, 4, 0)$ and $(3, 4, -5)$, with the sphere radius $r = 5$, and center $\vec{c} = (3, 4, 0)$.  Applying above we get
$$\hat{n}_{(8, 4, 0)} = \left( \frac{8-3}{5}, \frac{4-4}{5}, \frac{0-0}{5} \right) = \left( 1, 0, 0 \right)$$
and
$$\hat{n}_{(3, 4, -5)} = \left( \frac{3-3}{5}, \frac{4-4}{5}, \frac{0--5}{5} \right) = \left( 0, 0, 1 \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\nabla ((x − 3)^2 + (y − 4)^2 + z^2 - 25)$$ $$=[2(x-3),2(y-4),2z]$$ Substitute the coordinates of the points of intersection into this expression. Remove the surplus factor of "2" from the vectors and then divide each vector by its norm.